# How to remove white space from the start of a String Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to create a program which reads a .txt file and splits the file into separate lists.

I am using this to try and split my strings into 4 parts:

`val parts = it.split("\\s".toRegex())`

```
 val part1 = parts[0]
 val part2 = parts[1]
 val part3 = parts[2]
 val part4 = parts[3]
```

(The reason i am using "\s" is that the number of spaces between the words in inconsistent)

However, some lines in the file begin with a space or two which then results in the first word not being detected.

Is there a way for me to ignore or remove only the first white space of each line? As currently when i try to print part[0] it returns as blank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is probably something like this:

```
val textLine = " part1 part2 part3  part4"

// wrong way
val parts = textLine.split("\\s".toRegex())
println(parts) // [, part1, part2, part3, , part4]

// correct way
val partsWithTrim = textLine.trim().split("\\s+".toRegex())
println(partsWithTrim) // [part1, part2, part3, part4]
```

Note the `trim` call to remove white spaces from the start and the end of the string and the `+` sign in the regex part to really deal with inconsistent number of spaces.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I have another question if you done mind.

Comment: The first 3 lines in the file contain a different amount of words, for example the first line contains just one work and the 3rd 3 words. I am unable split the file inot 4 sections as the first line results in a indexOutOfBounds error. what would be the best way to read the file in Kotlin in such a way that i can skip the first 4 lines? Or is there another way to manage this problem? Currently i am using  `File("filename").forEachLine{}`

Comment: This is hard to answer because I don't know how you are using each of these parts. But, if you really need to save a variable for each part and access the elements by index, you should make a test before trying to access the list: `val part1 = if(parts.size > 0) parts[0] else null`. Again, if you have a variable number of words in each line, this is probably not the best way of doing it, but with the knowledge i have of your context, this is it.

Answer (score 5):

'val value = "          hello kotlin"

value.trimstart()      // output: "hello kotlin"

value.trim()    // output: "hellokotlin" `

Comment: The additions of example input/output could be edited into Bruce's reply instead of being posted as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply trim the strings:

```
 val part1 = parts[0].trim()
```

or

```
 val part1 = parts[0].trimStart()
```